Binary.createFromBase64 with pymongo
In mongosh, I use
db.my_collection.find( { my_field: Binary.createFromBase64('k4FyS0OWT6ujgLUAZKnsLw==', 3) } )

How to replicate the the part Binary.createFromBase64 inside a python script with pymongo ?

try something like this? from bson.binary import Binary and  cursor = collection.find({'my_field':Binary(base64.b64decode('k4FyS0OWT6ujgLUAZKnsLw=='),3) })

if worked you cna write answer
